# Windows 10 Java Web Start desktop shortcuts don't get created

Tags: java, jnlp, shortcut-file

On Windows 10 I'm facing problems at creating desktop shortcuts of my Java Web Start Application.
In my JNLP I have set this parameter:

`<shortcut online="true">`
 `<desktop/>`
 `</shortcut>`
But this doesn't help. I also checked my Java settings at the Java Control Center->Advanced->Shortcut creation tab. But this doesn't help neither.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My support here, I'm receiving an uninformative message from java too.